# Alinhar ao centro div com tamanho variavel

Tags: css

Olá, tenho uma div pai que defini com `min-width:800px` e `max-width:1400px`, como faço para que esta div sempre fique alinhada ao centro?

Comment: Para você que é novo no site de uma olhada [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 1):

Coloque as margens automáticas:

```
.exemplo {
   min-width:800px;
   max-width:1400px;
   margin-left:auto;
   margin-right:auto;
}
```

Comment: isso mesmo que eu queria, valeu!